# What is function behaviors in SiteController.php?

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am starting up with yii2
I dont have any idea of previous version of YII
But I have good knowledge of codeigniter and have been working in codeigniter from last 3 years.

MY Question is as below :

There is a function name `behaviors()` in SiteController.php file.
It has below code. I want to know what does it do?

```
public function behaviors() {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: 'public function behaviors()
{
return [
'access' => [
'class' => AccessControl::className(),
'only' => ['logout'],
'rules' => [
[
'actions' => ['logout'],
'allow' => true,
'roles' => ['@'],
],
],
],
'verbs' => [
'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
'actions' => [
'logout' => ['post'],
],
],
];
} 
0
'

Comment: [Yii 2 Guide: Authorization](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html) and [Yii 2 VerbFilter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-verbfilter.html)

Answer (score 1):

In the sample you privided  there are two part

```
'access'
```

and

```
'verbs'
```

the access section  configure the Access Control Filter   rules 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html
one of the authorization method implemented  by Yii2 ( best used by applications that only need some simple access control)

and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-verbfilter.html
that  define  the allowed HTTP request methods for each action. VerbFilter checks if the HTTP request methods are allowed by the requested actions. If not allowed, it will throw an HTTP 405 exception. 
In  your case set that the action logout must performed by a post method

for a brief guide you can see

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-filters.html